# How can I correctly construct a method extension using Groovy language in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy

I searched the web and tried the solution offered from this [site](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html)

I did the constructing file:

```
"src/main/resources/META-INF/
 services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule"
```

Inside this file contains the following text:

```
moduleName = extensions
moduleVersion = 1.0
extensionClasses = main.Extensions
```

When I tried to compile, eventually it did not worked. It still not recognized the extension method. I hope you have an idea to make this worked correctly, thanks in advance.